# How to use shell wildcards with sudo?

Tags: command-line, sudo, wildcards

I am trying to take out all the contents of folder1 and drop it into the images_temp folder that folder1 is in:

```
jeatonhomes@jeatonhomes.com [~/images_temp]# sudo mv folder1/* .
mv: cannot stat `folder1/*': No such file or directory
```

Yet I am getting that error above, I tried to look up the answer here but there are answers that I do not believe apply to my situation. Please help.

```
jeatonhomes@jeatonhomes.com [~]# pwd && ls -l
/home/jeatonhomes
total 108
drwx--x--x  18 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Apr  3 13:25 ./
drwx--x--x 106 root        root        4096 Mar 30 16:19 ../
lrwxrwxrwx   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes   37 Dec 18  2015 access-logs -> /usr/local/apache/domlogs/jeatonhomes/
-rw-------   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes  628 Apr  3 13:25 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes   18 Sep 22  2015 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes  176 Sep 22  2015 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes  124 Sep 22  2015 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x   2 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Aug  4  2016 cache/
-rw-r-----   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes   20 Jan  4 14:10 .contactemail
drwx------   5 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Mar 20 22:39 .cpanel/
drwx------   4 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Aug  4  2016 .cphorde/
-rw-rw-r--   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes   15 Apr  3 13:26 .dns
drwxr-x---   2 jeatonhomes mail        4096 Jul 22  2016 etc/
-rw-------   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes   17 Mar  8 22:39 .ftpquota
drwxr-x---   2 jeatonhomes nobody      4096 Dec 18  2015 .htpasswds/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root        root        4096 Apr  3 13:45 images_temp/
-rw-------   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes  211 Jan  4 14:09 .lastlogin
drwx------   2 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Apr  1 08:16 logs/
drwxr-x--x   8 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Dec 18  2015 mail/
drwxrwxr-x   4 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Jan  4 14:27 perl5/
drwxr-x---   3 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Dec 18  2015 public_ftp/
drwxr-x---   7 jeatonhomes nobody      4096 Apr  3 06:06 public_html/
drwx------   2 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Jan  4 14:10 .ssh/
drwxr-xr-x   5 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Feb 15 06:34 ssl/
drwx------   2 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Nov  3 22:55 .subaccounts/
drwxr-xr-x   7 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Jul  6  2016 tmp/
drwx------   2 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes 4096 Dec 18  2015 .trash/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes   11 Dec 18  2015 www -> public_html/
-rw-r--r--   1 jeatonhomes jeatonhomes  658 Nov 10  2015 .zshrc
```

Also, I got this error:

```
jeatonhomes@jeatonhomes.com [~/public_html]# wp media import 
/home/jeatonhomes/images_temp/* --title="Images for East 46th West 59th and Sycamore Road" --alt="New Images  for April"
Warning: copy(/home/jeatonhomes/images_temp/62262529_0.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in phar:///usr/local/bin/wp/php/commands/media.php on line 292
Error: Could not create temporary file for /home/jeatonhomes/images_temp/62262529_0.jpg.
jeatonhomes@jeatonhomes.com [~/public_html]# sudo wp media import /home/jeatonhomes/images_temp/* --title="Images for East 46th West 59th and Sycamore Road" --alt="New Images  for April"
[sudo] password for jeatonhomes:
sudo: wp: command not found
```

Comment: Are you positive there are files inside `folder1`?

Comment: yeah, so I think I know what happened, I uploaded these folders from local machine to server via root and it is not giving me access via username now.

Comment: so we probably need more info. it could well be the permissions issue, but you tried it with sudo which should mitigate permissions issues. Can you provide the output from this command, please: `pwd && ls -l`

Comment: added more info

Comment: Your `ls -l` indicates that `folder1` does not exist. That would explain why trying to copy files from it fails.

Comment: @dhag the `folder1` is inside `~/images_temp` (which does exist), and we haven't been shown the contents of either of those folders.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In

```
sudo mv folder1/* .
```

Your shell (so running as *you*, not `root`) is expanding (well, trying to expand) that `folder1/*` glob.

That results in a number of arguments to pass to `sudo mv`. However here, you (contrary to `root`) don't have read access to that directory, so the glob fails to match any file. Your shell is one of those broken (IMO) shells like `bash` or `sh` where when a glob doesn't match, it is passed as-is.

So instead of the shell returning an error to tell you it didn't find any file matching that pattern, it passed the `folder1/*` string literally as an argument to `sudo mv`. And `mv` complains that it can't find a file called `folder1/*` (thankfully harmless in this case).

Here, you'd want that glob to be expanded by root, so you'd need to start a shell *as root* to expand that glob:

```
sudo sh -c 'mv folder1/* .'
```

Comment: nice answer.  It would be great to know which, if any, shells aren't "broken" with respects to globbing, unlike `sh` and `bash`.

Comment: @gregory, the pre-Bourne sh for instance, or csh, tcsh (that behave like pre-Bourne sh), or fish or zsh. In bash, you can set the `failglob` option to get a similar behaviour.