# "sudo -s <command>" runs command in a shell, but wildcards or metacharacters not working

Tags: shell, sudo

When using `sudo -s` (short for the ["--shell" option](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.26/sudo.man.html#s)), it is possible to pass "sudo" a command, in which case it will run the command in a shell started by "sudo" as the target user.

(Similarly, `sudo -i`, also available as the ["--login" option](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.26/sudo.man.html#i), also starts a shell and similarly accepts a command, which behaves the same way.)

Running commands in sudo via a shell can be important in many cases:

- When using wildcards under a directory the current user doesn't have access to, but root does, the command needs to run under a root shell to have the wildcards properly expanded.
- Running a whole pipeline, many commands chained in pipes (`|`).
- When running a shell built-ins, such as `for`, `if`, etc. Running a small whole inline "script" under a single `sudo` can be useful.

The documentation of the ["-s" option](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.26/sudo.man.html#s) says (emphasis mine):

> Run the shell specified by the `SHELL` environment variable if it is set or the shell specified by the invoking user's password database entry. *If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's **-c** option*. If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed. Note that most shells behave differently when a command is specified as compared to an interactive session; consult the shell's manual for details.

In other words, when passing `sudo -s` a command, it is passed to the shell using the `-c` option, which takes a string with a "script" and then proceeds to execute it as a shell script.

The documentation doesn't really go much further on how to use this option, or to present examples, except to say "consult the shell's manual for details." This implies the command received is passed *directly* to the shell's `-c` option. However, as it turns out, that is not the case.

Passing it a shell script with multiple words fails:

```
$ sudo -s 'ls -ld /var/empty'
/bin/bash: ls -ld /var/empty: No such file or directory
```

The error message implies it's trying to run the whole string as a simple command... Hmmm, ok, so maybe add spaces would work? Yes that's the case:

```
$ sudo -s ls -ld /var/empty
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 18 Jul 12 21:48 /var/empty
```

That's not really how the shell's `-c` works though... Oh well, let's try to use some metacharacters, such as `~`, which is a shortcut for the home directory, to see how this behaves. Note the `~` needs to be quoted, to prevent the non-sudo shell from expanding it (in which case it would expand to the home of the non-root user, rather than `/root` which is expected):

```
$ sudo -s ls '~'
ls: cannot access '~': No such file or directory
```

Ok, so that doesn't work, and the error output seems to imply the expansion is not happening, since it's preserving a literal `~` there.

What about wildcards? Not working either:

```
$ sudo -s ls '/root/*.cfg'
ls: cannot access '/root/*.cfg': No such file or directory
```

In both these cases, running the command with `$SHELL -c` works just fine. In this case, `$SHELL` is bash, so:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'ls ~'
anaconda-ks.cfg
$ sudo bash -c 'ls /root/*.cfg'
/root/anaconda-ks.cfg
```

One exception is that variables seem to work on `sudo -s`, such as:

```
$ sudo -s echo '$HOME'
/root
```

So:

- What is going on here?
- Why do wildcards and metacharacters such as `~` do not work on the command passed to `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`?
- Given `$SHELL -c` takes a single string with a script, but `sudo -s` takes multiple arguments, how is the script assembled from the arguments?
- What is a reliable way to run commands on a shell via `sudo`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use shell wildcards with sudo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355656/how-to-use-shell-wildcards-with-sudo)

Comment: @IporSircer That question does not explain why `sudo -s <command>` does not work... The motivation for this question was [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/483379/281844) in which I suggested using `sudo -s`, but it turns out that doesn't work. I searched for it, and didn't find any other questions addressing why that doesn't work, so I decided to document it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** When taking a command on the "--shell" or "--login" options, `sudo` will escape most characters (using backslash escapes), including all metacharacters (except for `$`), also including spaces.

That breaks about every use case where you'd want to use a shell, which makes `sudo -s` mostly unsuitable to run shell commands that *need* to run as shell commands.

Instead of `sudo -s`, use `sudo sh -c '...'` or `sudo bash -c '...'` (or whatever the expected `$SHELL` is.) Instead of `sudo -i`, use `sudo bash -l -c '...'` instead (assuming root's shell is bash again.)

---

Looking at [the relevant part of the sudo source code](https://github.com/millert/sudo/blob/SUDO_1_8_26/src/parse_args.c#L571), there's this snippet:

```
/* quote potential meta characters */
if (!isalnum((unsigned char)*src) && *src != '_' && *src != '-' && *src != '$')
    *dst++ = '\\';
*dst++ = *src;
```

The snippet runs over each character of each argument. If the character is not alphanumeric, underscore, dash or dollar sign, it will be escaped with a backslash.

This means wildcards `*`, `?`, `[...]`, etc. will be escaped to `\*`, `\?`, `\[...\]`.

Also metacharacters such as `~`, `;`, `|`, etc. will be escaped to `\~`, `\;`, `\|`.

A string with spaces `ls /root` will be escaped to `ls\ /root`.

For some reason, `$` is an exception in escaping, that's why `sudo -s echo '$HOME'` works, since the `$` will be kept unescaped. (Note this only works for variables, and not even the `${HOME}` form, in which case the curly braces will be escaped, which will break the expression.)

---

The consequences of this quoting is that most cases that *require* running a shell as root can't really benefit from the `sudo -s <command>` format:

- Wilcards won't be expanded, since they'll be escaped and won't work as wildcards.
- Pipelines won't work, since the pipe `|` will be escaped and won't work either.
- Commands like `for` and `if` typically need to use `;`, which will be escaped and won't work either. A newline would be an alternative, but there doesn't seem to be a way to introduce an unescaped newline either.

In short, the form `sudo -s <command>` only seems to work for cases that don't involve wildcards, pipelines, scriptlets, etc. But then, **you typically don't really need a shell to run those commands!** Just running `sudo <command>` without the `-s` is typically enough for those cases.

It's unclear what the motivation for the sudo implementation. Perhaps to maintain some consistency between handling of commands when adding or removing the `-s`. Perhaps also because `-i` precedes `-s` and in that case there's some small difference in how environment variables are set...

---

**WORKAROUND:** The workaround is to run the shell's `-c` explicitly.

This involves knowing what `$SHELL` is for the target user (which might not match the current user, so using `$SHELL` directly is not always correct.)

For instance, instead of `sudo -s ls -l '/root/*.cfg'`, use:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'ls -l /root/*.cfg'
```

And instead of `sudo -i ls -l '~'`, use:

```
$ sudo bash -l -c 'ls -l ~'
```

(bash's `-l` argument creates a "login" shell, which is equivalent to the one created by `sudo -i`.)