# How to properly format the command argument for sudo?

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line, scripting, sudo

I have a command that is similar to this minimal example:

```
$ sh -c 'echo "1=$1"' _ foo
1=foo
$
```

When I want to run it through `sudo`, it stops working:

```
$ sudo -i -u user -- sh -c 'echo "1=$1"' _ foo
1=
$
```

Comment: "When I want to run it through `sudo`, it stops working" – Not because of sole `sudo`, but because of `sudo -i`. Possibly related: [*`sudo -s <command>` runs command in a shell, but wildcards or metacharacters not working*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484363/108618).

Comment: workaround: use braces. `sudo -i -u user -- sh -c 'echo "1=${1}"' _ foo`